# How do I modify the size of an embedded Gist?

Tags: github, gist

Is it possible? As it is, it just seems rather large on my webpage currently, and I'd like to shrink it down.

If it makes a difference, I'm using the standard embed code displayed alongside the Gist. In my case, that's `<script src="https://gist.github.com/4090046.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you:

- change the source of that GitHub js script (and store it on your website)
- want to do any other kind of modification (like shrink that GitHub Javascript yourself, and call that shrink-ed version), with services like [packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/),

you won't be able to get a shorter js script from GitHub itself.

Comment: I wasn't looking for shorter Javascript code, I was looking for a way to reduce the dimensions. Currently it takes up the entire width of my div, which is way too big.

Comment: @dantdj same kind of answer: you would have to rewrite it yourself (and store that script on your site), in order to customize it the way you want it.

Comment: Ah, looks like I'm stuck with my cludgy workaround, then. Ah well...